# Setup NPM prepublish minify script

Tags: npm, minify

I want to setup a script that will minify my Javascript code before I publish it using NPM.

As far as I understand, this should be possible using this in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "prepublish": "somethingThatMinifies"
}
```

What tool is the best/most commonly used for minification in this situation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Little bit late but hope it still helps someone (like myself, who got here from a Google search about "prepublish").

I believe [uglifyjs](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) is one of the most popular minification and compression tools.

You could use it like this:

```
"scripts" : {
  "prepublish" : "uglifyjs -o myfile.min.js myfile.js"
}
```

Just make sure to add `uglify-js` to your `devDependencies`.

See [uglifyjs](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) for options and more information on how it works. If your minification process gets too complex, you could create a `Makefile` and use something like:

```
"scripts" : {
  "prepublish" : "make minify"
}
```

Comment: `./node_modules/.bin/` is added to the path when an npm script is run, so you can drop that from your first `prepublish` script.

Answer (score 1):

So just to update @mkretschek answer, now we should use either `prepare` or `prepublishOnly` to run our minification script before publish a package at npm, since `npm 4.0.0` `prepublish` is deprecated.

**prepare**

> Runs any time before the package is packed, i.e. during **npm publish** and **npm pack**

**prepublishOnly**

> Runs BEFORE the package is prepared and packed, ONLY on **npm publish**.

---

Then our `package.json` looks like:

```
"scripts" : {
  "prepublishOnly" : "uglifyjs -o myfile.min.js myfile.js"
}
```

Reference: [npm scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/scripts)